# How to build a small documents storage?

Tags: java, database, architecture, lucene, full-text-search

Suppose I need to build a storage for text documents. The storage should contain documents (just text files) and their metadata: the creation date and a few dozens *tags* for each document. The number of documents to store is ~10^6 (each document is ~10K).

The primary language is `Java` and the storage should be deployed in `Windows`.

Users should be able to store documents and their metadata in the storage and search documents by the date range and *tags*: e.g. get all documents from the last week with tags: *tag1* and *tag2*.

Suppose we store the documents in the file system and add an *index* to store the documents names (paths), their dates, and *tags*. How would you build the index ? Would you use an RDBMS (e.g. `mySQL`) for that ? Would you use `Lucene` or any other full text search engine ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [JackRabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/), which is a JSR-170 compliant Java document store ?

> The Apache Jackrabbit™ content repository is a fully conforming
>   implementation of the Content Repository for Java Technology API (JCR,
>   specified in JSR 170 and 283).
>
> A content repository is a hierarchical content store with support for
>   structured and unstructured content, full text search, versioning,
>   transactions, observation, and more.

Note (re. your question) that it uses Lucene under the covers.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I do not need versioning, transactions, observation etc. It looks an overkill for me. Don't we have a simpler solution?